# Calculate the number of workdays between two dates in HOURS

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code that I found on microsoft website :

```
Function Work_Days(BegDate As Variant, EndDate As Variant) As Integer
 
 Dim WholeWeeks As Variant
 Dim DateCnt As Variant
 Dim EndDays As Integer
 
 On Error GoTo Err_Work_Days
 
 BegDate = DateValue(BegDate)
 EndDate = DateValue(EndDate)
 WholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", BegDate, EndDate)
 DateCnt = DateAdd("ww", WholeWeeks, BegDate)
 EndDays = 0
 
 Do While DateCnt <= EndDate
 If Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sun" And _
 Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sat" Then
 EndDays = EndDays + 1
 End If
 DateCnt = DateAdd("d", 1, DateCnt)
 Loop
 
 Work_Days = WholeWeeks * 5 + EndDays
 
Exit Function
 
Err_Work_Days:
 
 ' If either BegDate or EndDate is Null, return a zero
 ' to indicate that no workdays passed between the two dates.
 
 If Err.Number = 94 Then
 Work_Days = 0
 Exit Function
 Else
' If some other error occurs, provide a message.
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
 End If
 
End Function
```

It works fine, but I would like to get the difference in hours, but it's not working. I Changed the "d" for "h", but instead of giving me the exact hours, it's giving me 24 hours.

When I change "d" for "h" and multiply 1 by 24, and 5 by 24, I dont get the exact difference in hours. This is what I get :

```
Date1   Date2   DIFFERENCE
2022-05-05 09:05:19;    2022-05-05 15:45:14;    24
```

it's giving me 24h instead of 6h

Comment: Well, cannot you just multiply the days by 24 to get the hours?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but never `Format(DateCnt, "ddd") <> "Sun"`, always `Weekday(DateCnt) <> vbSunday`, your current code will break as soon as the OS language is set to anything but English.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected as said. What i'm asking is that i would like to have the difference between dates in hours and not in days. How to modify the current code to get the difference in hours? @ErikA

Comment: I edited my question to add example of my result @ErikA

Comment: Eeh.. That's as simple as `INT((Date2 - Date1) / 24)`, dates in Access are internally stored as days since 1899-12-30 00:00:00 which means you can calculate with them.

Comment: @ErikA I dont think you understood what I need.. Let's say date 1 and day 2 are 2 hours a part, well I want to see 2 hours as a result. Let's take another example. Day 1 is friday 4PM, Day 2 is Monday 9 AM. I want the difference in hours between these 2 dates while EXCLUDING the weekend.

Comment: Well, then calculate the number of weekend days that have elapsed and remove them

Answer (score 0):

The Work_Days function returns the number of weekdays as a whole number. Time is not considered.

This code returns weekday hours between two dates with a time component.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function Weekday_Hours(BegDateTime As Variant, EndDateTime As Variant) As Long

    ' Weekday hours between two dates with a time component
    
    Dim WholeWeeks As Long
    Dim DateCurrent As Date
 
    Dim BegDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    
    Dim BegTime As Date
    Dim EndTime As Date
    
    Dim EndDays As Long
    
    Dim Week_Days As Long
    
    Dim FirstDay_Hours As Long
    Dim LastDay_Hours As Long
    
    Dim FirstDay_Minutes As Long
    Dim LastDay_Minutes As Long
    
    ' If the weekend, move the start date to Monday 12AM
    If Weekday(BegDateTime) = vbSaturday Then   ' 7 - Saturday
        Debug.Print Weekday(BegDateTime) & ": Saturday"
        
        BegDateTime = DateAdd("d", 1, BegDateTime)
        BegDateTime = Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Debug.Print " BegDateTime:" & Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
    End If
    
    If Weekday(BegDateTime) = vbSunday Then     ' 1 - Sunday
        Debug.Print Weekday(BegDateTime) & ": Sunday"
        
        BegDateTime = DateAdd("d", 1, BegDateTime)
        BegDateTime = Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Debug.Print " BegDateTime:" & Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
    End If
    
    BegDate = DateValue(BegDateTime)
    Debug.Print "         BegDate: " & BegDate
    
    EndDate = DateValue(EndDateTime)
    Debug.Print "         EndDate: " & EndDate
    
    If BegDate >= EndDate Then
        Debug.Print "Adjusted BegDate >= EndDate"
        Weekday_Hours = 0
        Exit Function
    
    Else ' (BegDate < EndDate)
        FirstDay_Hours = DateDiff("h", BegDateTime, BegDate + 1)
        Debug.Print "  FirstDay_Hours: " & FirstDay_Hours
        
        FirstDay_Minutes = DateDiff("n", BegDateTime, BegDate + 1)
        Debug.Print "FirstDay_Minutes: " & FirstDay_Minutes
        
        BegDateTime = DateAdd("d", 1, BegDateTime)
        BegDateTime = Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        
        BegDate = DateValue(BegDateTime)
    End If
    
    EndTime = TimeValue(EndDateTime)
    Debug.Print "     BegDateTime: " & Format(BegDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
    
    EndDate = DateValue(EndDateTime)
    EndTime = TimeValue(EndDateTime)
    Debug.Print "     EndDateTime: " & EndDate & " " & EndTime
    
    WholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", BegDate, EndDate)
    Debug.Print " " & "     WholeWeeks: " & WholeWeeks
    
    DateCurrent = DateAdd("ww", WholeWeeks, BegDate)
    Debug.Print "     DateCurrent: " & DateCurrent
        
    Do While DateCurrent < EndDate
        If Weekday(DateCurrent) <> vbSunday And _
          Weekday(DateCurrent) <> vbSaturday Then
            EndDays = EndDays + 1
            Debug.Print "         EndDays: " & EndDays
        Else
            DateCurrent = Format(DateCurrent, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        End If
        
        DateCurrent = DateAdd("d", 1, DateCurrent)
        Debug.Print "     DateCurrent: " & Format(DateCurrent, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
    Loop
    
    Week_Days = WholeWeeks * 5 + EndDays
    Debug.Print "       Week_Days: " & Week_Days
    Debug.Print " Whole day hours: " & Week_Days * 24
    
    BegTime = TimeValue(BegDateTime)
    Debug.Print "     BegDateTime: " & BegDate & " " & BegTime
    
    LastDay_Hours = DateDiff("h", BegTime, EndTime)
    Debug.Print "   LastDay_Hours: " & LastDay_Hours
    
    LastDay_Minutes = DateDiff("n", BegTime, EndTime)
    Debug.Print " LastDay_Minutes: " & LastDay_Minutes
    
    ' Weekday hours
    Weekday_Hours = FirstDay_Hours + Week_Days * 24 + LastDay_Hours
    Debug.Print "   Weekday_Hours: " & Weekday_Hours
    
    Weekday_Hours = (FirstDay_Minutes + LastDay_Minutes) / 60 + Week_Days * 24
    Debug.Print "   Weekday_Hours: " & Weekday_Hours
    
End Function


Private Sub Weekday_Hours_test()

    Dim BegDateTime As Variant
    Dim EndDateTime As Variant
    
    ' Whole day hours: 0
    ' LastDay_Hours: 6
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 400
    ' Weekday_Hours: 6 / 7 when using minutes
    BegDateTime = "2022-05-05 09:05:19"
    EndDateTime = "2022-05-05 15:45:14"
    
    ' ?
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-05 15:45:14"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05 09:05:19"
    
    ' Weekday_Hours: 0
    'BegDateTime = "2022-04-30 09:05:19" ' Saturday
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-01 15:45:14" ' Sunday
    
    
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 9
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 495
    ' Whole day hours: 0
    ' LastDay_Hours: 9
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 545
    ' Weekday_Hours: 18 / 17 when using minutes
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-04 15:45:14"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05 09:05:19"
    
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 15
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 895
    ' Whole day hours: 96
    ' LastDay_Hours: 15
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 945
    ' Weekday_Hours: 126 / 127 when using minutes
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-05 09:05:19"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-12 15:45:14"
    
    ' *** Monday starts at 12AM
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 24
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 1440
    ' Whole day hours: 48
    ' LastDay_Hours: 15
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 945
    ' Weekday_Hours: 87  / 88 when using minutes)
    'BegDateTime = "2022-04-30 09:05:19" ' Saturday
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05 15:45:14"
    
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 15
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 895
    ' Whole day hours: 24
    ' LastDay_Hours: 15
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 945
    ' Weekday_Hours: 54 / 55 when using minutes)
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-05 09:05:19"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-07 15:45:14" ' Saturday
    
    
    
    ' *** When time is not entered the default is 12AM ***
    
    ' Weekday_Hours: ?
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-05"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05"
    
    ' One day not two
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 24
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 1440
    ' Weekday_Hours: 24
    'BegDateTime = "2022-05-04"
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05"
    
    ' Three days not four
    ' FirstDay_Hours: 24
    ' FirstDay_Minutes: 1440
    ' Whole day hours: 48
    ' LastDay_Hours: 0
    ' LastDay_Minutes: 0
    ' Weekday_Hours: 72
    'BegDateTime = "2022-04-30" ' Saturday
    'EndDateTime = "2022-05-05"
    
    
    If EndDateTime > BegDateTime Then
        Debug.Print "   Weekday_Hours: " & Weekday_Hours(BegDateTime, EndDateTime)
    Else
        Debug.Print "?"
    End If
    
End Sub
```